# C printf Format Specifier %_fi

Tags: objective-c, c, printf, specifier

Does anyone know if an underscore as format specifier (like %_f) does anything in C code? 
I+ve found some code in a book that uses it, but I've googled and found nothing. I've also tested the following Objective-C code in Xcode and Xcode seems not to support this specifier. Is it valid in C?

```
-(void) print {
    printf( "%_f + %_fi", real, imaginary );
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps this is meant to symbolize a space character for the purpose of the book?

Comment: Some compilers apparently support this for "optimal" display of a double - see http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/printf.html

Comment: If what Jens proposed is true, the format specifier is `% f` though. Note the trailing `i` is not part of the format.

Comment: Even if it was to symbolise a space between % and f, what would be the benefit of that space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [OS X man page for `printf()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/printf.3.html) says this:

> - An optional separator character (  `,` | `;` |  `:` | `_` ) used for separating multiple values when printing an AltiVec or SSE vector,
>     or other multi-value unit.
>
>   NOTE: This is an extension to the `printf()` specification. 
>     Behaviour of these values for `printf()` is only defined for operating
>     systems conforming to the AltiVec Technology Programming Interface
>     Manual.  (At time of writing this includes only Mac OS X 10.2 and
>     later.)

Comment: I think this is not the case, as we are printing doubles, not vectors.

Comment: The separator is used by `printf()` "when printing an AltiVec or SSE vector, or other multi-value unit". When not printing such a multi-value unit, it presumably is not used. The presence or absence of the "v" length modifier is what determines if the argument is interpreted as a vector value. (See further down the man page.) So, effectively, the underscore does nothing in this case.